# How to convert DataType of schema to another in scala spark dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataFrame in which instead of IntegerType I have LongType in schema the DataFrame is stored in json format . How should I convert all the column with LongType to IntegerType.

Comment: can you post your sample json format ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
df.select(df.schema.map(s => if (s.dataType == LongType) col(s.name).cast(IntegerType) else col(s.name)): _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small dataframe you can simply cast all the columns:
(This isn't advised for large datasets as this uses a mutable dataframe)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, LongType}

val cols = dataFrame.columns()

// mutable dataframe
var tmpDf = dataFrame

for(col <- cols){
    if(dataFrame.schema(col).dataType == LongType){
        tmpDf.withColumn(s"${col}_int", dataFrame[col].cast(IntegerType))
    }
}

// convert back to immutable
val dataFrame_2 = tmpDf
```

Comment: Yes , The dataFrame is large I think it wil create. a problem

Comment: See the other answer here - it should work better and on large datasets